# How can I find required sample size to meet certain condition in R?

Tags: r, sample-size, descriptive-statistics

I need to find the required sample size to meet certain condition in R. The question where I need help is posted below.

---

Suppose a forester would like the sample mean to be within 1 square inch of the population mean, with probability .90. How many trees must he measure in order to ensure this degree of accuracy?

This is the question where I get stuck. I manually solved this and got n = 3. However, I'm not sure how to get same/similar result in R. On the bottom, I also included a previous problem that's connected with this one.

---

A forester studying the effects of fertilization on certain pine forests in the Southeast is interested in estimating the average basal area of pinetrees. In studying basal areas of similar trees for many years, he has discovered that these measurements (in square inches) are normally distributed with standard deviation approximately 4 square inches. If the forester samples n = 9 trees, ﬁnd the probability that the sample mean will be within 2 square inches of the population mean.

For this one, I solved in R in two different ways.

Method 1:

```
pnorm(1.5) - pnorm(-1.5)
```

Method 2:

```
set.seed(4302019)

Z <- rnorm(10000)

x <- (abs(Z) < 1.5)

mean(x)
```

Comment: HI there, welcome to Cross Validated! Though I believe your question is more suited to Stack Overflow, I've edited so it's easier to read. Also, by a quick look at Google you can find some helpful material regarding your question, [here is one](https://www.r-bloggers.com/calculating-required-sample-size-in-r-and-sas/).

Comment: R would only be used to implement a method for doing this. First, you need a method that is valid & that you understand clearly. I think this Q is appropriate for [stats.SE] & should be considered on-topic here.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).